# Python: Sort optimally and compare

Tags: python, list, sorting

How do I  arrange a list A such that the maximum number of elements of list A are greater than another list B?

EXAMPLE:

```
A='3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1' 
B='2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6'
```

answer=7..................If I sort the lists,

```
      sListA = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9]
      sListB = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]
#if sListA[i]>sListB[j]: count +=1
```

There are 5 instances where  `sListA[i]  > sListB[j]`

but we need to maximize instances where  `sListA[i] > sListB[j]`.., ie, 7

If sListA was `[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 6, 6]`

and slistB was`[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]`

then 7 instances of `sListA[i] > sListB[j]` will be possible..

Heres my code:

```
 def main():
        listA=list(map(int,A.rstrip().split()))
        listB=list(map(int,B.rstrip().split()))
        sListA=sorted(listA)
        sListB=sorted(listB)
        count=0
        for (i,j) in map(sListA,sListB):
            if sListA[i]>sListB[j]:
                count+=1
        print(count)         
    main()
```

**But this only counts from sorted lists, I need to find a way to swap elements with the next largest element in sListA when `sListA[i]<sListB[j]` 
to maximize instances where sListA[i]>sListB[j]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in theory this should do what you wanted:

```
A='3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1' 
B='2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6'

def main():
    listA = sorted(list(map(int,A.rstrip().split())))
    listB = sorted(list(map(int,B.rstrip().split())))
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(listA)):
        if listA[i] <= listB[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            listA[i], listA[j] = listA[j], listA[i]
            j += 1
    return listA
print(main())
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 6, 5, 6]
```

In essence, all I did was add an `else` to your `if` structure to keep `i` counting and swap elements over in `listA`

---

Previous answer (if you are interested in the outcome of 7 specifically):

```
A='3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1' 
B='2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6'
def main():
    listA = sorted(list(map(int,A.rstrip().split())))
    listB = sorted(list(map(int,B.rstrip().split())))
    cnt = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(listA)):
        if listA[i] > listB[j]:
            cnt += 1
            j += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return cnt
print(main())
```

---

To do this for multiple lists of A and B maybe try to apply something like:

```
Alist=['3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1', '9 5 3 1 0']
Blist=['2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6', '5 4 3 4 6']

def main():
    cnt = 0
    for x in range(len(Alist)):
        listA = sorted(list(map(int,Alist[x].rstrip().split())))
        listB = sorted(list(map(int,Blist[x].rstrip().split())))
        j = 0
        for i in range(len(listA)):
            if listA[i] > listB[j]:
                cnt += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                i += 1
    return cnt
print(main())
```

Comment: not yet, I have to do the comparison with mutated listA and listB to finally get 7 as the answer

Comment: I am interested in only the answer, but It has to work for any number of random test cases.

Comment: Although It passed the initial test case, It failed a few others.

Comment: it worked..with this.
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TYEmqTQ3ZuhZU7Q4LKa5TA30xQelZqxqu9mRqlK0Xd0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

maybe not the most efficient but you can try

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9]
b = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]
b.sort()
a.sort()

new_a = []
for bb in b:
    idx_v = np.where(np.array(a) > bb)
    if idx_v[0].size == 0:
        break
    else:
        e = a.pop(np.min(idx_v[0]))
        new_a.append(e)
new_a.extend(a)
```

you'll find that

```
np.sum([new_a[n] > b[n] for n in range(len(b))])
```

is 7, and

```
new_a
```

[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 9, 5, 6, 6]

Comment: the ```np.where``` will find the indices of all the elements in a > bb. Since a and b are sorted, you'll need to take the first of them (then the np.min) and remove it from the list a. It is not a daft question: don't hesitate to ask if some other clarification is needed :)

Comment: I didn't think about it when writing, but this should work for lists of different lengths too.

Comment: I know it will, but then, the stupid platform I am coding in won't let me import any libraries XD